# How to get phpMyAdmin's Display Chart after a query and output on web page using php

Tags: php, charts, phpmyadmin, display

is there any possible way of taking the display chart generated in phpMyAdmin after a successful query and embed it in my code to output it on my web page using php ? Without the use of any other api or plugin like fusionchart ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You have a PHP wrapper for nnnick/Chart.js.
https://github.com/HugoHeneault/Chart.js-PHP

If you want to display simple charts and if you don't know much about javascript this link is usefull.